# Performance: using array in the object namespace vs local array

Tags: javascript, performance, firebug

I was playing with some javascript performance optimizations and found something interesting. Here is the code:

```
function gObject() {

    this.obj = [];
    this.LIMIT = 100000;

    this.doLoopLocal = function () {
        var o = [];
        for (var i=0;i<this.LIMIT;i+=1) {
            o.push(i);
        }
        return o;
    };      

    this.doLoopObject = function () {
        this.obj = [];
        for (var i=0;i<this.LIMIT;i+=1) {
            this.obj.push(i);
        }
    };
};

var g = new gObject();

console.time('Using Local array');
g.doLoopLocal();
console.timeEnd('Using Local array');

console.time('Using Object array');
g.doLoopObject();
console.timeEnd('Using Object array');
```

When I run it, the log tells me that using local arrays is slower than using array defined  in the object namespace. The difference is significant - 8 to 10 times! (FF 18.0.1)

```
Using Local array: 16ms
Using Object array: 2ms
```

A screenshot:[image]

I was always assuming that using objects defined locally within a function is faster, but this experiment shows me wrong. Why would this be happening?

**UPDATE:** I tried the script in the local Firefox console and the numbers are something that I expected in the first place: using local array outperforms using object array. So the real cause is Firebug that for some reason skews the numbers and show incorrect result. Something to keep in mind.

Comment: I pasted this code into my console in chrome and the local array took 2 ms and Object array took 3 ms.. interesting.  What if you swapped the order, run the local second?

Comment: I just also ran this in Chrome and got: "Using Local array: 1.675ms
Using Object array: 3.585ms" the first time. After repeating the very same code three times i get "Using Local array: 2.316ms
Using Object array: 1.673ms". Even more interesting...

Comment: Local array took 1ms and object array took 6ms in Chrome for me.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/using-array-in-the-object-namespace-vs-local-array jsperf here

Comment: Was too slow writing my [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/this-vs-var-in-loop), tried to reduce code to just interesting bits.

Comment: Yes, Chrome shows totally opposite (and faster) numbers to me. Is it just a Firefox thing?

Comment: I've added another test to the jsperf - http://jsperf.com/using-array-in-the-object-namespace-vs-local-array/3 - in my case, the OPs results aren't replicated, and the new test shows how you can alias a local variable to the object's property and avoid the repeated property resolution.

Comment: @Vlad: It's more of a "don't sweat it" thing. Different implementations will always have different optimizations, and the next release from a particular browser could make all your testing/optimizing efforts obsolete.

Comment: @PaulS. yeah, yours is better

Comment: admit the work done by IE10, it shows not bad performance

Comment: I don't trust a console for performance testing. Change the order of the tests so that you're testing the `Object array` first, and see if your results remain consistent.

Comment: I always been interesting in this, would we gain any perks using something like `var i=0 for (;i<this.LIMIT;i+=1) {
                o.push(i);
            }` instead of `for (var i=0;i<this.LIMIT;i+=1) {
                o.push(i);
            }`

Comment: @thesystem I tried the local Firefox console and you know what - the numbers are more comparable now - it even shows that Local is faster. This is weird. So it seems that it is Firebug that messes up the results. I should have known.

Comment: @Vlad: Yeah, I've heard that Firebug can mess with performance testing. You may get better results in the built-in console for Firefox.

Comment: I've added Internet Explorer 5.5 and 6.0 results to jsperf.com/using-array-in-the-object-namespace-vs-local-array/3 They don't do well, I wonder why... :)

Comment: If you figured it out yourself, then maybe write an answer and vote it the answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

As always with magic, the magic lies in the eyes who believes it's happening.
What are you testing here by the way ? If we forget that, in your doLoopObject, you do not return this.obj, just testing a few times shows that the results are 'random', even worse : if you reverse the order of the tests, they might change depending on Browser. 
And results will depend on the time you wait in between two clicks. If you wait a few seconds, they will always be almost equal.
Now be attentive, on JSPerf, to the speed the numbers are growing, and, especially on Firefox the explanation  becomes quite obvious : there are periodic slow-down : the garbage collector is triggered by such garbage creating functions. When it triggers, the figures will increase more slowly, might it be for an object or a local var (it doesn't matter). 
What you are measuring here is the garbage collector time, NOT the push() time on an object property compared to a local variable. That explains why the order, and the time in between tests, changes things.
I will add that the change in between two tests is far too big to conclude anything.

But most important is that, when waiting enough, both tests performs the same on FF/Safari...

The only conclusion you can draw from all this is : both methods performs the same.

BUT Since anyone allocating that much 'heap' would anyway allocate at once, using the simple myArray[lastIndex-1]=0, i'm afraid the real conclusion is : this test shows nothing.